Chain array formulae
Is it possible to chain array formulae?
i.e.)
Assume a column of values such as "Max", "Michael", "Kyle", "Michael" starting in A1
Then a formula such as =UNIQUE(A1:A4) in A2 ("Max", "Michael", "Kyle")
Is there a way to put a second formula in A3 such as =LEN(A2) that will return an array {3, 7, 4} and spill to the below rows?
I want to create effectively an automatically-updating table that expands based on the output of UNIQUE, that keeps certain intermediate results between the initial array and the final column of calculated values.
I do not want to have to use something like MAP(UNIQUE(A1:A4), LAMBDA(x, LEN(x))) as many intermediate steps use long, complex formulae and the resulting lambdas and inputs would rapidly become very cumbersome and difficult to edit.

Welcome to Superuser! I am assuming you mean B2 and B3 as A2 and A3 already contain values. S0, in B2, why can't you use =LEN(UNIQUE(A1:A4))?

You can refer to the results of a dynamic formula in the worksheet using the spilled range operator # e.g.:


Thank you so much! I read through the excel docs but failed to spot this one.

At least UNIQUE() is only available in O365/Excel...
